# I created deque<CObject*> and added different type of element. How can I change attribute of this elements?

Tags: c++, deque

I created:

```
class CMap:{
public
std::deque<CObject*> obiekty;
}


class CBullet{
public:
int damage;
}
```

and I added different type of element ( e.g.  CTank, CBullet...)
and I want change atributes using deque

```
for( size_t i=0; i<game->Mapa->obiekty.size(); i++){

 if(typeid(*(game->Mapa->obiekty[i]))==typeid(CBullet)){                                       
  this->HP=this->HP - game->Mapa->obiekty[i] (?? my problem/I can't do it ?? ->damage); 

}
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and finally provide a [mcve].

Comment: As far as I understood you are looking for [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), though there is usually better ways of achieving this (e.g.: `virtual` functions)

Comment: yes. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to inherit your derivate classes(`CBullet`, `CTank`) from base class (`CObject`), like this

```
//Base clase
class CObject
{
public:
    //...
    virtual ~CObject(){}; // Don't forget about virtual desctructor
};
class CBullet: public CObject
{
public:
    //...
    ~CBullet(){};
    void DoBulletMethod(){};
};
class CTank: public CObject
{
public:
    //...
    ~CTank(){};
    void DoTankMethod(){};
};
```

Then you can check all objects by `dynamic_cast`, like this:

```
for( size_t i=0; i< game->Mapa->obiekty.size(); i++)
{
    if(dynamic_cast<CBullet*>(game->Mapa->obiekty[i]) != nullptr)
    {
        CBullet * BulletObj = dynamic_cast<CBullet*>(game->Mapa->obiekty[i]);
        BulletObj->DoBulletMethod();
    }
    else if(dynamic_cast<CTank*>(game->Mapa->obiekty[i]) != nullptr)
    {
        CTank * TankObj = dynamic_cast<CTank*>(game->Mapa->obiekty[i]);
        TankObj->DoTankMethod();
    }
}
```

Or you can use polymorphism and create virtual methods, without further detection of current object type, for example create one virtual method in base class and override it in derivate classes:

```
//Base clase
class CObject
{
public:
    //...
    virtual ~CObject(){}; // Don't forget about virtual desctructor
    virtual void DoActionInLoop()
    {
        //No action in base class
    }
};
class CBullet: public CObject
{
public:
    //...
    ~CBullet(){};
    virtual void DoActionInLoop() override
    {
        std::cout << "I am bullet I can do here my tasks" << std::endl;
    }
};
class CTank: public CObject
{
public:
    //...
    ~CTank(){};
    virtual void DoActionInLoop() override
    {
        std::cout << "I am tank and I can do here my tasks" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Then just call this method on each `CObject*` instance and get your polymorphism:

```
for( size_t i=0; i< game->Mapa->obiekty.size(); i++)
{
    game->Mapa->obiekty[i]->DoActionInLoop();
}
```